# How to merge vectors into a list in R?

Tags: r

What I get is:

```
 > list("",rep(0,2))
 [[1]]
 [1] ""

 [[2]]
 [1] 0 0
```

But what I expect to get is like this:

```
 [[1]]
 [1] ""

 [[2]]
 [1] 0

 [[3]]
 [1] 0
```

Does anyone know how to get the merged result?
Thanks!

Comment: You're applying `unlist` before using `list`, so it is useless. Also `(rep(0, 2))` does not return a list but a vector.

Comment: Yes, I know ``unlist`` is useless. And my question is : how to flatten the vector ``(rep(0,2))``

Comment: It IS flat... what you want is to change it to a list with `as.list`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want:

```
c(list(""),rep(0,2))
```